# start uwsgi failed in centos?

Tags: python, centos, uwsgi

I have intalled uwsgi through

```
yum install uwsgi
```

then I typed

```
service uwsgi start
```

to start uwsgi,it's failed,why?

[image]

I want to use uwsgi+nginx to deploy my python web,I have read the doc of 
https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/WSGIquickstart.html ,when I
typed

```
uwsgi --http :9090 --wsgi-file foobar.py
```

it reported 
[image]

how to solve this problem?

The uwsgi.ini is like this
[image]

Comment: start it as a superuser

Comment: I have logined as the root user

Comment: please post your uwsgi.ini

Comment: I have supplemented it in my question

Comment: finally,after I  installed  setuptools and python-devel,it has start successfully!! thanks!~